# data from htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, urlfetch

i want to fetch all data from htaccess i know it is stupid type of question
but i just wanted to know whether it is possible to get only user-friendly links from list of htaccess rules

```
RewriteRule ^login$ common/login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^forgot-password$ common/forgotpassword.php [L]
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ common/page_content.php?pageslug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^activate/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ common/activate.php?type=$1&userid=$2&activationcode=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^forgot-password$ common/forgotpassword.php [L]
```

i want this data in format as

```
$data->array(); //is array
$data[0] = login common/login.php 
$data[1] = forgotpassword common/forgotpassword.php or simlar to this
```

or please suggest me some way to get all tags inside my site along with their path names
i want to build my site-map dynamically based on htaccess

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have now?

Comment: hello ultimater i want to get data from .htaccess file not from the url, when a run function for htaccess file it will give me detail of all data in htaccess file

Comment: Are you trying to parse the contents of the .htaccess file itself in order to understand what it does?

Comment: please review the question i have edited it again

Comment: Aha, so parsing the .htaccess file it is. That's much more clear, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)$ common/$1.php?getValues=$2 [L,NC]
```

you can use this code you can make good urls with this
example:

if you want go common/forgot-password.php
yoururl.com/forgot-password
for go page "aboutus"
yoururl.com/page/aboutus its mean: common/page.php?getValues=abouts
you can get the page slug with $_GET['getValues']
or for multiple datas

yoururl.com/activate/type/userid/key meanÇ: common/activate.php?getValues=type/userid/key
and parse with explode:

```
$datas=explode("/",$_GET['getValues']);
echo "type: $datas[0]
userid: $datas[1]
key: $datas[2]";
```

Comment: thanks for your help but this is not what i want i want my hole urls of htaccess to insert into an array, i don't data from urls, i want to fire function on htaccess to get all data from .htaccess file

Comment: please explain me i want to do it very badly

Comment: Paste this to your .htaccess file and the first attribute is your file name. You can use "/" for use attiributes  and in your .php file parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Untested but I think you're looking for something like this:

```
function rewriteLink($link)
{

    if(preg_match('/^login$/',$link)){return "common/login.php";}
    if(preg_match('/^forgot-password$/',$link)){return "common/forgotpassword.php";}
    if(preg_match('/^page/(.*)$/',$link,$m)){return sprintf("common/page_content.php?pageslug=%s",$m[1]);}
    if(preg_match('/^activate\/([a-zA-Z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/(.*)$/',$link,$m)){return sprintf("common/activate.php?type=%s&userid=%s&activationcode=%s",$m[1],$m[2],$m[3]);}
    return $link;
}
```

p.s. your .htaccess file contains two duplicate forgotpassword.php re-write statements, for the function I have written above I have based it on your htaccess file but omitting the 2nd redundant instance from my code logic.